# When i Change id of a component of one activity it also changes the id of component of other activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I am creating an blog app(ANDROID).
This app is having many activities like signup_activity, signin_activity, userProfile_activity etc.

I have created the layout of my signin_activity from the scratch and then i copied all the xml code and pasted in the signup_activity and made required changes so that i dont have to write whole xml code again for signup_activty because signup_activity and signin_activity dont have much difference.

But the problem is When i try to change the id of an component(let say EditText for email) in signin_activity then it also changes the id of the corresponding EditText in signup_activity.

I know i could have write the whole xml code for signup_activity from scratch to avoid this ambiguity but i want to know why this is happening? Is this Android Studio or something else which is causing the problem??.

I am currently using android studio 3.3
And i am creating my activity design using constraint layout with the help of editor.

xml code:

```
enter code here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
tools:context=".LoginActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/logo" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtLoginEmail"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="93dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textColorHint="#fff"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtLoginPassword"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtLoginEmail" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCreateAccount"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:padding="18dp"
    android:text="Login to Account"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtLoginPassword" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/b" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:text="Sign Up"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.01"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3" />

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using Refactor > Rename? Are you using the same ID for both EditText?

Comment: No i am not using that . i am simply changing the components id in editor

Comment: please share some of your xml layout with us so we can detect the problem(kind of hard with noting to work with)

Comment: i have shared the xml code(signin_activity). and i copy this code to create signup_activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was reading the comments, and it seems you are copying this Login activity XML code in the other XML file too. 
Though copying the code shouldn't make a difference, I think the line creating your problem would be `tools:context=".LoginActivity"`

Remove this line from the other XML file. It should hopefully work fine then. Just a suggestion!